# Let's clean up the Data Structures for Interviews question

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, answer-quality, locked-question

### [Why are data structures so important in interviews?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102041/why-are-data-structures-so-important-in-interviews)

This question has almost 60,000 views, and is in the top 50 in views in questions that are not closed.

However, it's pretty clearly off topic, asking us why we think that interviews happen a certain way falls under both the **primarily opinion-base** close reason and under the **career advice** close reason.

So it needs a historical lock, but I'm not prepared to flag for that yet as it needs a pretty solid cleanup first, [according to the guidelines.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103053/how-aggressively-should-we-maintain-and-improve-very-popular-questions/103069#103069)

- Several of the answers are really just comments and should be converted or deleted
- Old comments that add nothing of value need to be deleted
- Other things I'm probably not thinking of

This is a request for help editing the question to a lockable form, including 20k+ and moderators to assist in deleting the bad answers.

Comment: related: [Can we please cleanup this popular question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7375/31260)

Comment: I downvoted a bunch of answers that added nothing of value beyond what the top five or six answers provided. It might help if more people did the same, then we categorically delete all nonpositive scored answers.

Comment: @Snowman I think you forgot to downvote [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/102064/31260) (FTFY:)

Comment: looks like we've got a problem. That [guidance for mod cleanup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103053/how-aggressively-should-we-maintain-and-improve-very-popular-questions/103069#103069), it appears to be given for open questions. While practice for locks is opposite, "mod only locks without cleanup". We probably have to pick, either cleanup or lock. Or justify exception to do mod cleanup prior to lock in this particular case (which could be difficult)

Comment: @gnat Those are the rules for moderators; the community can and should use our powers as we see fit. That's why even 20k+ don't have nearly the powers mods do. These answers shouldn't be downvoted or deleted if we as a community think they should remain or add anything to the question

Comment: @gnat Also, I think the main thing that Jeff was objecting to in that answer was deleting **all** the answers and rolling them into **one big answer**. Deleting the bad answers was fine according to him: **"It's OK to combine answers, but not into one giant single katamari ball answer."**

Comment: I see, good logic. You did really smart not limiting call to cleanup to moderators. :) That way looks doable. I saw at 10K tools page that many answers there already got delete votes from 20Kers, we only need to get more of them to complete this

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]? 11 worst answers deleted, question closed and locked